# Format Airflow logs in Json - Issue

Tags: logging, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Following [Format Airflow Logs in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016338/format-airflow-logs-in-json) and the guide mentioned in it, I copied log_config to airflow/config folder. But when I run the webserver or scheduler, I get 'module not defined' (**init**.py was defined in the config folder) And PYTHONPATH was set as airflow/config

Error was

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 40, in configure_logging
    logging_config = import_string(logging_class_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/module_loading.py", line 33, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.config'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import conf
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    settings.initialize()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 374, in initialize
    LOGGING_CLASS_PATH = configure_logging()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 52, in configure_logging
    'Unable to load custom logging from {} due to {}'.format(logging_class_path,err), isinstance('airflow',dict), isinstance('airflow.config',dict), type('airflow.config')
ImportError: ("Unable to load custom logging from airflow.config.log_config.LOGGING_CONFIG due to No module named 'airflow.config'",
```

Now it returns,
`ImportError: Unable to load custom logging from airflow.config.log_config.LOGGING_CONFIG due to section/key [logging/logging_level] not found in config`

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

In case you haven't already figured it out.
It looks like the code that loads the `logging_level` is looking for it to be in a section named `logging` in the `airflow.cfg file`

But, this attribute actually resides under `core` section by default
So if you'll change your code to `LOG_LEVEL: str = conf.get("core", "LOGGING_LEVEL").upper()`
this should resolve for you, or you can add another `[logging]` section in your airflow.cfg. (requires some reordering)

Answer (score 1):

Follwing the same answer like Meny Issakov:

**Solution**:

1. Go to your file `airflow.cfg`
2. Include a below the `[core]` section the following code:

   ```
   [logging]
   logging_config_class = log_config.DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG
   ```
3. Restart your scheduler

**Reason of problem:**
The file `airflow.cfg` is missing a section called `[logging]`.

**Understanding the problem**

At the time that the scheduler starts, it access the `[core]` section in the `airflow.cfg` and search the logging path.

And the information where the logs will be stored it's found in `logging_config_class` parameter.

However, even if we put `logging_config_class = log_config.DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG` in the `[core]` section, the scheduler it's not gonna work either.

Why? It's because there's a mismatch between the `log_config.py` logging handlers and with the `airflow.cfg`.

In the logging handlers in the `log_config.py` they have the following `conf.get` to get the logging configurations:

```
LOG_LEVEL: str = conf.get('logging', 'LOGGING_LEVEL').upper()  
LOG_FORMAT: str = conf.get('logging', 'LOG_FORMAT')
```

The first parameter it's the section that will be scanned in the `airflow.cfg` file, but by default, there's no section called `[logging]` in the `airflow.cfg` file, and this causes the following error in the scheduler inicialization:

`ImportError: Unable to load custom logging from log_config.DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG due to section/key [logging/fab_logging_level] not found in config`

Comment: This is the best answer for this issue, I spent like 3 hours on this issue, feeling stupid   .